# Can't start WEBrick with Byebug on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, byebug

When I try to run `rails server`, I get the following:

```
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
```

The only way I managed to start WEBrick is by commenting out `gem 'byebug'` in the Gemfile.

At first I though it was Byebug's fault, but trying to run `rails console` gives me:

```
/home/fabio/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
from /home/fabio/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /home/fabio/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
[...]
```

It seems I messed up at some point of the installation, but where?

Comment: The OP is using rbenv, not RVM.

Comment: I'm using rbenv.
`$ rbenv -v
rbenv 0.4.0-129-g7e0e85b`

Comment: Just to make sure, did you run `bundle install` after each time you changed your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Yes, I get `Your bundle is complete!`.

Comment: Why are you using Byebug? It's a debugger and isn't useful in normally running programs.

Comment: It's a default.
All I did was:
`gem install rails;
rails new test_app`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced my steps back and found some info on the [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/wiki#suggested-build-environment) page that could be related.

I ran `$sudo apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev` as suggested and reinstalled ruby (using rbenv).

Rails runs just fine now, no need to comment out Byebug. I can also run `rails console` now.